# Get value of function in another file returned in array

Tags: function, magento

I have a function in a file where it is informing values in array but I need to get those values in another file.

I am using magento and need to get information from the function where it has the name of the client that made the request, I tried to get the first_name but it did not work.

FileOne.php

```
public function getCustomerInfo($customer, $order)
    {

        $email = htmlentities($customer->getEmail());
        if ($email == "") {
            $email = $order['customer_email'];
        }

        $first_name = htmlentities($customer->getFirstname());
        if ($first_name == "") {
            $first_name = $order->getBillingAddress()->getFirstname();
        }

        $last_name = htmlentities($customer->getLastname());
        if ($last_name == "") {
            $last_name = $order->getBillingAddress()->getLastname();
        }

        return array('email' => $email, 'first_name' => $first_name, 'last_name' => $last_name);
    }
```

FIle Two.php

```
require(../Model/fileone.php

public function getName(){

            $name = $this->getCustomerInfo($customer, $order);
            $first_name = $name['first_name'];
            return $first_name;
    }
```

I need to display the name of the client that is in first_name, but it is not showing.

Comment: Shouldn't `getCustomerInfo()` in `FileTwo.php` pass with 2 parameters; `$customer` and `$order`?

Comment: Hey, I think your `require` function is missing a close bracket and a semicolon. Also, check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp) out.

Answer (score 0):

You have two files, one with a function you would like to call from another.

To use the `getCustomerInfo()` function from another file, you will need to import the class that contains that function (using `use` or `require_once()`).

If you import the other file, then referencing the function will not use `this->` before the function call because the `getCustomerInfo()` function is not part of the same class as the `getName()` function.

Since in the examples you provided, these functions are not part of classes, you should be able to `require_once(fileOne.php);` at the top of fileTwo.php, and the call `getCustomerInfo()` anywhere within that file.

*When calling `getCustomerInfo()` it needs to have two arguments, per the declaration of the function.*

Comment: is there a way to call first_name without require?

Comment: In order to get `first_name` you have to call `getCustomerInfo()` since `first_name` is part of an array it returns. In order to do that you must import `getCustomerInfo()`, which you could do in a few ways: use fileOne.php;, include('fileOne.php');, require('fileOne.php').

Comment: public function getName(){

            $name = $this->getCustomerInfo($customer, $order);
            $first_name = $name['first_name'];
            return $first_name;
    }
I inserted require, in my function in filetwo how to get first_name now?

Look at what I entered and returned error.

Comment: You need to remove the $this-> at the beginning of the `getCustomerInfo()` function. Also, `$customer` and `$order` must be a value that the can be parsed by the function.

It seems like I am missing the purpose of this code and may not best give solutions because of this misunderstanding, Elaborating on what you are trying to do would give me more information to give advice.

Comment: MOdified: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getData() on null in /var/www/html/vendor/mercadopago/magento2-plugin/src/MercadoPago/Core/Helper/Data.php

Comment: Ok, so I have no idea what is in Data.php and cannot diagnose your problem with just a pasted error statement.